# Lookup Functions not giving exact result

Tags: vlookup, lookup

I have a little problem getting the result i wanted from the data that i have.

I tried index match match and vlook up match but it doesnt give me the result that i wanted.

Please see the sample data that I have. [DATA 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14uWo.png)

I wanted to get the # of hours based from this table [TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdGSr.png)

Can someone help me get the correct syntax for this please?

Tried several things to go around the with formulas but ended up either just 1 result for the whole column or an error. Thanks

up for this.

Comment: Are you headers for the "TABLE" string or datetimes? Seems like all you need are multiple conditions e.g. name = name and date matches. Are your headers text or styled dates?

Comment: Headers in table are in date timees..
my lookup value are names, # of hours and date.

Comment: Not helping fully yet, but never use vlookup. You want a mixture of ifs match and indirect functions. vlookup is too inaccurate

Comment: Any chance you could upload the data to an accessible medium. Can't be bothered typing out the data from the photos.

Comment: Basically you want to match on the row (name) then the column (date). From that you want to build an indirect reference

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHZOKZqrgIlgkAT6GkkQKUmBRaOZD2q3jhWdQ0HdFTs/edit#gid=1763217541

That is the sheet i copied from the original file.

Comment: so basically i jsut want to fill in the # of hours matching with date and names.. 

ill try the indirect approach so I may need to study it though, sorry not really good in excel that much. Thanks.